# Why was an app secret not required for this Facebook app to work?

Tags: facebook, authentication, heroku

I've been experimenting with making Facebook apps and I'm still not clear on app IDs and secrets.

I tried [this code on github](https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-ios-client) and got it working. I noticed that it only requires an app ID and the correct url to work, but nowhere do you need to enter an app secret.

Why was an app secret not required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app secret is not required on the client side. In fact, it is a security risk to store the app secret on the client side. By client side I mean in JavaScript, iOS, etc. The only purpose for the app secret is on your web server. For example, if you are making an API call from PHP on behalf of the user you must use the app secret.

Comment: Can you give an example of such an API call?

Comment: If you're using the PHP SDK: **$me = $facebook->api('/me');**

Comment: Oh, I've used a call like that before. But where's the app secret?

Comment: $facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => $app_id,
   'secret' => $app_secret
   ));